# Оповестить директиву об изменении параметра

Tags: angularjs, typescript

В одном из комментариев здесь прочитал:

> Насколько я знаю, если дело доходит до $watch / $observe, то это результат неправильной архитектуры кода.

и задумался, что пожалуй может быть более удачный способ моей проблемы.

У меня есть директива, в которую как параметр передается одна из переменных контроллера.  Например:

```
<dm-my-directive var="item" />
```

Директива, в зависимости от значения этой переменной должна что-то посчитать и соответственно отобразить.

Проблема в том, что значение этой переменной `item` получается в контроллере от внешней веб-службы, а значит с некоторой задержкой. То есть, сначала отрабатывает контроллер директивы (при `typeof(item) == undefined`) и лишь потом от веб-службы в контроллер приходит нужное значение для этой переменной.

Мне в директиве надо как-то понимать, что для этой переменной наконец-то пришло значение и значит она себя должна перерисовать.

Для этих целей в директиве я и использую `$watch`. А может есть более удачные варианты?

На всякий случай подчеркну два важных момента:

1. Переменная `item` меняет свое значение только один раз - когда значение будет получено от веб-службы. Все остальное время она не меняется.
2. Перенести обращение к веб-службе в эту директиву - не вариант, так как а) есть куча параметров вне директивы, которые влияют на запрос к веб-службе б) этот `item` кроме директивы активно используется и вне директивы

**Добавлено**

Контроллер представления на котором расположена директива:

```
constructor(public $scope: any, 
            public itemResource: app.common.ItemResource) {

    itemResource.itemsByAutoincrementedId(this.itemTypePosition).then((curItem: app.domain.Item) => {
                this.Item = curItem;
            });
}
```

Код самой директивы:

```
constructor(public $scope:any) {

  $scope.$watch('item', () => {

     if(typeof($scope.item) === "undefined") return;

     // ... here is business loginc
```

Сам запрос сводится вот к такому коду:

```
getRequest(url: string): ng.IPromise<any> {

    var deferred = this.$q.defer();

    this.$http({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: учитывая что в ангуляре **все** построено на _$watch / $observe_ можно заключить, что у него не правильная архитектура :-D

Comment: добавьте пример вашей директивы, и пример ее использования

Comment: добавил.  у меня там typescript, но, думаю, идея понятна

Comment: а версия ангуляра? 1.х или 2.х?

Comment: использую первую версию

Comment: так, а из сервиса Resource возвращается или что?

Comment: `itemResource.itemsByAutoincrementedId` - это просто $http GET запрос, который в `then((curItem: app.domain.Item)` возвращает typescript класс

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33897/discussion-between-grundy-and-demas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу пару вариантов

1. Так как переменная меняется только *один* раз, нет смысла следить за ней постоянно, поэтому надо просто при первом изменении отписаться.

   ```
   var unsubscriber = $scope.$watch('item', () => {
       if(typeof($scope.item) === "undefined") return;
       ... //logic
       unsubscriber();
   });
   ```
2. Так как запрос возвращает promise - можно его просто и пропихнуть в директиву - и там уже работать в callback для функции then

   ```
    $scope.item = itemResource.itemsByAutoincrementedId(this.itemTypePosition);
   ```

   и в директиве

   ```
   $scope.item.then(...)
   ```